# pushing new object to array - cant get push() to work - using LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've tried a few stack examples. an i am still just rewriting what i was hoping to be adding to ... mainly we have a list of check box items each time you check it i would like existing items to turn into a list of those object so we can use them on a 'comparing' page

```
const handleChange = () => {
   localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(products)); <-- works as expected
   var existingItems: any[] = [];
   existingItems?.push({ products });
   localStorage.setItem("compareItems", JSON.stringify(existingItems));
};
```

existingItems is always = to products i want existing items to = [{item}, {item},] and so on

detail of what products would be:
products (object of key and values frm api) = {name: "Product 1", description: "Product 1", isActiveForEntry: true, displayRank: 0, sku: "ABC123"}

Comment: what is products? can you add more code

Comment: added it to the above sean, it's just an object with keys and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the existing items first before defaulting to an empty array:

```
const existingItems: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("compareItems")) ?? [];
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
existingItems.push({ products });

localStorage.setItem("compareItems", JSON.stringify(existingItems));
```

See [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) for what the `??` means.

Comment: thank you!! i tried something similar to your answer earlier and wasnt helping. This is spot on i just needed an ! added like so 

 const existingItems: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("compareItems")!) ?? [];

now it is adding to the array and not replacing :)

Answer (score 1):

At each method invocation, you are initializing `existingItems` object then storing its value with one item being the `products` hence the stored object will only hold one item at a time.

You should retrieve the `compareItems` stored value being your `existingItems` then append the new `products` objet to it:

```
const handleChange = () => {
   localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(products));
   const compareItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("compareItems"));
   var existingItems: any[] = compareItems ? compareItems : [];
   existingItems.push({ products });
   localStorage.setItem("compareItems", JSON.stringify(existingItems));
};
```

Comment: thank you this worked just as well! i do end up not needing the {} around products